# Wordpress wants to install itself, rather than run the blog

Tags: wordpress

We have created a duplicate of our website on a new server as part of a migration. We have a wordpress blog that is part of our website.

The docroot of the wordpress site is set as an alias in our main site. The result is that to access the site home page, the following url is used: https://www.rephunter.net/blog/.

The new environment is not available to the public at this time, and is only accessible within our VPN. When the above link to the blog is followed, instead of the expected home page of our blog, we get the page at https://www.rephunter.net/blog/wp-admin/install.php, which wants to install a new site.

The configuration in the new environment is supposedly an exact copy of our production site from some time back. The permissions on the main files is the same.

What is it that is causing the attempted blog access to be redirected to the installation script?

EDIT:

The responses so far have not really absorbed the intent of the previous information. We are not migrating in the normal sense. Rather we are testing in a new virtual environment that will eventually lead to a more normal migration.

We have an exact duplicate of our original wordpress and database environment that is running in a virtual environment with an updated protocol stack that is only accessible if you are on the VPN for that environment. As far as we can tell, there is no difference in the configuration.

For example, the parameters in wp-config.php are exactly the same as in the original installation. When php runs, it sees the same environment, with host names and everything identical. It would not work otherwise.

Yet if there really were no difference, it would just run. But since WP is trying to install a new database, there is something different that we are missing.

To further illustrate this: supposed you took an image backup of the wordpress installation and the database, and put it in a different VM, and set up the DNS and everything as it needs to be--the new environment looks no different than the old one. All databases, wp-config settings, etc, are the same. So our main website and database functions very similarly.

As I mentioned above, the difference in the protocol stack should be considered.  The old system is on PHP 5.6.27--the new one is on 7.3.4. So that could be causing some difference, which maybe somebody might recognize. Wordpress is 5.2.2 and should be compatible with both PHP levels.

We believe there is some relatively simple parameter setting that we are missing. For example, as in the first answer that $table_prefix is set wrongly. But that is not it in this case.

Comment: given that this is a virtual env could there be an issue with WP seeing the DB? Generally you only see the install screen when WP cannot successfully connect to the DB or has trouble accessing `wp_options` table (specifically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress redirects you to that installation screen because the database it's connecting to is working (meaning, the username and password are correct), but the data it's expecting to be there isn't. Therefore, it assumes it's a new / empty database and prompts you to install WordPress.

I've seen this happen in two scenarios:

1. The database really is empty, and thus WP needs to install the standard tables and info
2. The table prefix in your wp-config.php file is incorrect for an existing database

Look at your wp-config.php file in the root directory of WordPress, and look for a line similar to this:

`$table_prefix  = 'wp_';`

Then, open up the database (phpMyAdmin or some other interface to browse what the database structure actually is) and confirm that the table prefixes (the first few characters of the table names) actually match what's set above.

Hopefully this gives you something to go on! Let us know what you find

Comment: $table_prefix matches the prefix in the database.

Comment: Can you confirm that your connection info is DEFINITELY going to the correct database? The hostname / pw / un / and database name are all correct? In fact, is it possible to post the relevant portion of your wp-config.php file (with fake un/pw in place) so we can examine?

Comment: At first all parameters and settings appears correct and the database was in place. However, due to some redirection in our prototype version in the virtual machine, the database was being looked for in the wrong place. Once we got that sorted, the blog is running as expected. I am giving credit for the correct answer to this response because of the critical phrase in the first sentence "... data it's expecting to be there isn't." And that is exactly what was happening. It was not any settings in wp-config.php; it was our redirecting of the database location.

Answer (score 0):

Migrating Wordpress websites can be quite tricky. I've worked as a WP developer for a number of years and always struggled with manually migrating websites.

There are a number of factors to consider:

- WP stores a lot of installation specific information within the database. So you can't do a database dump and upload the export into a new database.
- Changing the website url within the `wp_options` table in the databased there are still other references to the original url scattered throughout the db.
- You could try a find and replace all using an editor that supports this sort of functionality *(vscode, sublime, atom)* but things always end up breaking and your doing tons of "find & replace" actions.

I have always relied on a 3rd party tool [Backup Buddy](https://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/) as it simplifies the entire backup and migration process and offers the peace of mind of having easily deployable backups for your website.

Backup Buddy allows you to export your website as a `zip` and then you can move the zip to any server you want and the plugin provides an installer script (`php`) to guide you through the migration of your wp site to any host and database of your choosing.

> Note: I am not in any way affiliated with iThemes or Backup buddy, and I do not stand to benefit in anyway if you decide to use the plugin. This is only advice on a tool that I have found helpful, reliable, have had success with, and currently actively use on a number of websites that I maintain.

Comment: I am going to edit the original question to make it more clear what we are doing.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress display installation page because you have not update your **wp-config.php** file after migrating server so please follow below steps in future when you migrate your website.

Please follow this steps when you migrate your WordPress website from one server to another server.

1. Back up your website files/database
2. Export wordpress database.
3. Create database on your new host server.
4. Edit the wp-config.php File and edit this details.

   1. Add new database name
   2. Add new database username
   3. Add new database user Password
   4. Add new host as per your hosting provider or (localhost is default)
5. Import your database to new server.
6. upload the WordPress files to your new host
7. defining new domain URL & [Search/Replace](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB) old domain URL

Comment: All these steps are in place, but it does not work. In particular, the db name, user, password and host are correct.

Comment: When you create new database on server so you have to assign the new user to database have you done this @JeffreySimon?